# how to convert column into rows of a table using MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below.

```
id      |  name   |   place_1  |  Place_2  |  place_3  |
------------------------------------------------------
12      | Anne    |   School   |           |           |
13      | Smith   |            | church    |           |
14      | Mari    |  School    |           |  Temple   |
15      | Nash    |            |           |  Temple   |
16      | Narmada |            | Church    |  Temple   |
```

What I want do is to count places separately and get a table only with following columns.
Just like `Place_1` , `Place_2` ,`Place_3` . And convert columns into rows using a stored procedure.

like below

```
Place   | count |
------------------
Place_1 | 2     |
Place_2 | 2     |
Place_3 | 3     |
```

can anyone help me to do that?

Comment: Do the places always appear in the same column or can they appear in any column - for example does School always appear in place_1?

Comment: Any time you see enumerated columns (above '2', say) alarm bells should start ringing. See normalization.

Comment: @P.salmon yeh. I consider place_1 as school , place_2 as church and place_3 as temple.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int, name varchar(10), place_1 varchar(10),  Place_2 varchar(10),  place_3  varchar(10));
insert into t values
(2       , 'Anne'    ,  ' School'   , null      ,    null     ), 
(13      , 'Smith'   ,  null        , 'church'  ,    null     ), 
(14      , 'Mari'    ,  'School'    , null      ,    'Temple' ),  
(15      , 'Nash'    ,  null        , null      ,    'Temple' ),  
(16      , 'Narmada' ,  null        , 'Church'  ,    'Temple' );


select   'Place_1' as place,count(*) 'Count' from t where place_1 is not null
union
select   'Place_2' as place,count(*) from t where place_2 is not null
union
select   'Place_3' as place,count(*) from t where place_3 is not null
```

Result

```
+---------+-------+
| place   | Count |
+---------+-------+
| Place_1 |     2 |
| Place_2 |     2 |
| Place_3 |     3 |
+---------+-------+
```